# Server for mobile feed app (like Instagram, Twitter...)?

Tags: mysql, database, webserver, hosting

I've made a mobile native app with a feed system like Instagram/Twitter. In development mode I was just running a PHP/MySQL Apache local server, but now I need to publish the app and work with a real server. Which kind of server do I need? I just need to send http requests (JSON), loads of them!

Do I just need a hosting server like 1and1? (http://www.1and1.com/linux-web-hosting?__lf=Static)
But this one, it only has 1GB MySQL databases... not enough

Is there any kind of app/server whatever? Which kind of server does Instagram use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days lots of users are moving to the cloud.

Check out Amazon EC2: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

You can setup a micro instance server and it is very cheap to run tests on and get off the ground. Then if you like how it's running, you can simply upgrade to a more powerful server without having to re-install everything.

It also allows you to scale if your application gets really popular by just cloning the server.

Really worth checking out.

Comment: My app uses httprequest with php mysql to communicate with the server. A hosting service wuldn't be enough?

Comment: You could use a hosting service for sure. I just prefer something like Amazon because it gives you more control over your machines. You have more power to configure your software however you want.